# Join a column in a table to multiple columns in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables in first table, I have a column(GDU) which contain hierarchical data like group, dept, unit in second table I have G, D, U (Group,Dept,Unit) as separate columns.

common key is GDU which I want to connect other table to recognize/segregate GDU to group, dept, unit

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried joining T1 & T2 on group then dept then unit, but it did not work out,

```
SELECT A2.*,B2.U 
FROM 
    (SELECT A1.*, B1.D 
     FROM 
         (SELECT A.*, B.G 
          FROM T1 A 
          LEFT JOIN T2 B ON A.GDU = B.G) A1
     LEFT JOIN 
         T2 B1 ON A1.GDU = B1.G) A2
LEFT JOIN 
    T2 B2 ;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @Dale K I have added the code that I prepared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use *self*-outer join ("self" because `t2` is being used 3 times; once for `G`, once for `D` and once for U`):`

Sample data (`t1` contains additional `rn` column, just for sorting purposes):

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (rn, gdu, amount) as
  3    (select 1, 'A' ,   100 from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'B' ,   150 from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'C' ,   125 from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'A1',   500 from dual union all
  7     select 5, 'B1',   800 from dual union all
  8     select 6, 'B2', 15000 from dual union all
  9     select 7, 'C2', 10000 from dual
 10    ),
 11  t2 (g, d, u) as
 12    (select 'A', 'A1', null from dual union all
 13     select 'B', 'B1', 'B2' from dual union all
 14     select 'C', 'C1', 'C2' from dual
 15    )
 16  --
```

Query begins here:

```
 17  select a.gdu, b.g, c.d, d.u, a.amount
 18  from t1 a left join t2 b on a.gdu = b.g
 19            left join t2 c on a.gdu = c.d
 20            left join t2 d on a.gdu = d.u
 21  order by a.rn;

GDU   G     D     U         AMOUNT
----- ----- ----- ----- ----------
A     A                        100
B     B                        150
C     C                        125
A1          A1                 500
B1          B1                 800
B2                B2         15000
C2                C2         10000

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Join to the table only once and use `OR` in the `JOIN` condition:

```sql
SELECT t1.gdu,
       CASE t1.gdu WHEN t2.g THEN t2.g END AS g,
       CASE t1.gdu WHEN t2.d THEN t2.d END AS d,
       CASE t1.gdu WHEN t2.u THEN t2.u END AS u,
       t1.amount
FROM   t1
       INNER JOIN t2
       ON (t1.gdu = t2.g OR t1.gdu = t2.d OR t1.gdu = t2.u)
ORDER BY g, d, u
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
 CREATE TABLE t1 (gdu, amount) AS
  SELECT 'A' ,   100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' ,   150 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,   125 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A1',   500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B1',   800 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B2', 15000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C2', 10000 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE t2 (g, d, u) AS
  SELECT 'A', 'A1', null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 'B1', 'B2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 'C1', 'C2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| GDU | G | D | U | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | *null* | *null* | 100 |
| B | B | *null* | *null* | 150 |
| C | C | *null* | *null* | 125 |
| A1 | *null* | A1 | *null* | 500 |
| B1 | *null* | B1 | *null* | 800 |
| B2 | *null* | *null* | B2 | 15000 |
| C2 | *null* | *null* | C2 | 10000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GQSPHx5m)